# Amazon - Redshift : Week number for a given date is coming wrong

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Considering Sunday as the first day of the week the below statements in redshift should return 2 as the week number instead returning 1.

Mysql has a function called [Week()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-week-function.php) where we can use the mode to get the desired result. Likewise is there any function in redshift that I could use to get the correct week number.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIMESTAMP '2018-01-07');

SELECT TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP '2018-01-07','WW');
```

Comment: It returns the same on PostgreSQL, so it should work the same way on Redshift. That's because the weeks begin on Mondays in both. Try querying for '2017-01-01', which was a Sunday, you'll get 52.

Comment: @Yankee, are you saying that on redshift the week starts on Monday? I thought it started on Sunday, is there a way to change this

Comment: @JorgeMadrigal Yes it does, because it's the same in Postgres. Here's something I found to change that in Postgres, should work in Redshift as well https://blog.0101010.com/making-date-trunc-use-a-sunday-week/

Answer (score 5):

date_part can be directly used for your use-case.

Query:

```
select date_part(w, '2018-01-07');
```

Here's a link for more details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_PART_function.html

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no direct solution to this, but here's a workaround:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIMESTAMP '2018-01-07'::date + '1 day'::interval);
```

[Source](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20051108065256.7DFE7D7971@svr1.postgresql.org)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while converting mysql to redshift.
This is how I fixed it.

```
TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('week', your_date + INTERVAL '1 day') - INTERVAL '1 day', 'ww')::INTEGER
```